# Opencv solvepnp() and ROS tf

Tags: ros, opencv, transform, tf-broadcaster

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using solvepnp() to get the pose of a checkerboard. But with a static marker  and a moving camera the rotations and translations are not correct.
solvepnp() gives a rotation in Rodriguez angles and a translation. Through a rotation matrix I convert this to quaternions. And broadcast this to tf as the transformation camera to marker. But is this the correct way?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/120106/opencv-solvepnp()-and-ros-tf/) by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2573 on 2014-01-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Nominally your approach sounds correct. You want to find the pose of the checkerboard int the frame of the camera and then publish a transform from the camera to the checkerboard.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0